# Pass Azure Devops $(Build.BuildNumber) to npm task

Tags: npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to update the package.json `version` through azure devops pipeline.
This is the task I used. But it throws error.

```
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: "npm version"
    command: "custom"
    workingDir: src
    verbose: false
    customCommand: "version $(Build.BuildNumber)"
```

How to correctly pass the pipeline build number to npm task.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *But it throws error.* **What** error? You need to provide as much detail as possible if you want to receive an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-version) `npm version <newversion>` to update the package.json `version`. for example, current version is v1.0.1, using command `npm version 2.0.0` will update its version to v2.0.0. Please note that the version format must be the same, like  `major.minor.patch`.

In addition, yaml pipeline will set the build numer to be formatted like `20210426.5` by default. If your package.json is not formatted like this, this command `npm version $(Build.BuildNumber)` will cause issues. You could use `UpdateBuildNumber` to [override the automatically generated build number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#updatebuildnumber-override-the-automatically-generated-build-number).

BTW, the following yaml pipeline is for your reference supposed that your package.json is formatted like `major.minor.patch`. Also you could use custom [variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) to specify the version number.

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Write your PowerShell commands here.
      
      Write-Host "Hello World"
      git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
      git config --global user.name "Your Name"

      echo "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]2.1.0"
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    workingDir: ''
    customCommand: 'version $(Build.BuildNumber)'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. This was the issue. Cheers